# Reduce white space within a chart in Vaadin Charts 2

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin-charts

Is there a way to reduce the vertical white space between the elements of a chart in [Vaadin Charts 2](https://vaadin.com/add-ons/charts)?

See the orange boxes in this screen shot.

[image: screen shot of a Vaadin Charts 2 chart with marks showing vertical white space]

While I understand this makes for an attractively laid-out chart, in my case I am assembling many charts with many lines within a layout. So I would like to maximize the amount of pixel used for the chart’s plot area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## First Orange Box

The first orange box is not actually white space within the chart. Or, if it is, I do not know how to change it.

## Second Orange Box

The second orange box is "margin" on the Title element. You can call the [`setMargin`](http://demo.vaadin.com/javadoc/com.vaadin.addon/vaadin-charts/1.0.0/com/vaadin/addon/charts/model/Title.html#setMargin(java.lang.Number)) method on the [`Title`](http://demo.vaadin.com/javadoc/com.vaadin.addon/vaadin-charts/1.0.0/com/vaadin/addon/charts/model/Title.html) object. For a small chart like that shown, I have found a value of `5` to be useful.

```
 this.getConfiguration().getTitle().setMargin( 5 );
```

## Third Orange Box

Likewise, the [`Legend`](http://demo.vaadin.com/javadoc/com.vaadin.addon/vaadin-charts/1.0.0/com/vaadin/addon/charts/model/Legend.html) object also offers a `setMargin` command. Again, I have found a value of `5` to be useful.

```
this.getConfiguration().getLegend).setMargin( 5 );
```

## Same Size Chart

The overall chart remains the same size. Only the space within that overall chart is changed, reallocated.

With both of these `setMargin` methods, the white space *between* the object and the plot area is reduced. The freed pixels are allocated to the plot area.

The difference can be significant, especially in smaller charts. Here is a screenshot of before and after adding calls to set margin to `5`. The scaling of the Y-axis changed because of the newly-gained pixels.

[image: screen shot of before and after calling 'setMargin(5)']